# Generating Ongoing Looping Links without Repeats using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, memory, random, storage

I am trying to create a button that sends users through a 'loop' of links, and keeps going through it anywhere, perhaps with its own 'memory'.

(REFERENCE CODE BELOW) For example, I want the first click to go to the first item, `/roles/mafia`, then the second click (from another tab, browser, or device) to go to the second one, `/roles/doctor`, and so on. When the button has been clicked six times (so the list has finished), the seventh time should loop back to the first one.

So if Bob clicks on the button with his Mac, it will take him to `/roles/mafia`.
But then seconds later, if Jill clicks on it with her `iPhone`, it will link to `/roles/doctor`, and so forth.

Here is my `JS`, but this doesn't work since this is a pseudo-random system, rather than forming a loop.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var urls = [
        "/roles/mafia",
        '/roles/doctor',
        '/roles/cupid',
        '/roles/mafioso',
        '/roles/pimp',
        '/roles/detective'
    ];

    function goSomewhere() {
        var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
        window.location = url; // redirect
    }
</script>
```

And then the HTML button:

```
<a href="#" onClick="randLink(); return false;" class="play-btn">JOIN SERVER</a>
```

I am aware this won't have a quite simple solution, and I'm very new to the concept of `JavaScript` and memory, so any help, even just a snippet to inspire another coder to find the answer, is enough.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: For what you trying to achieve you need to do it server side, so that any new request comes server is aware of already used link and it picks next from list. Hope that's a start you looking for, you can use node (javascript ), php or many other languages to achieve this.

Comment: It can not be done with javascript. You need to store last position per user. Javascript cookies/localStorage  are based on browser/session, not user. This should be handled by backend/db.